# How are device and application baudrate related?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, serial-port, baud-rate

I have a Bluetooth port (port A) with baudrate set to 9600 according to Device Manager. Within an application, a `SerialPort` object is created with `SerialPort.BaudRate` set to 2048 to read data transmitted via the Bluetooth module.

I would like to output received data from port A to another port (port B). However, it has to go through some signal processing, which may or may not affect the maximum baudrate. If I were to instantiate a `SerialPort` object for port B, what should I set the baudrate to? Also, what should its baudrate setting be in the Device Manager?

Comment: Use `2048`. The device manager setting is just the default value.

Comment: Would that ensure that same rate of transmission, even if there is heavy signal processing? I can't modify the reception rate since the speed of the Bluetooth module is fixed. I don't understand the Bluetooth protocol though, so I may be wrong.

Comment: What does signal processing have to do with this? When does this processing happen? Baud rate is related to the speed of the serial port, presuming that you're using the port to transmit meaningful data from one port to another. If a device connected to a serial port is using a certain baud rate, you need to configure the port to that value to get meaningful information. If your module specs say it communicates at 2048 baud, then use that value for your port and that's it. Perhaps your device is using TTL voltage levels, instead of RS232?

Comment: I take it that the baud rate setting in the Device Manager needs to be 2048? The receiver of Port B is hardware so I cannot manually set the baud rate on the receiving end. The problem is that 2048 is not selectable in Device Manager.

Comment: That's a bit strange, you can try something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1165692/69809) to get a list of supported baud rates, but I was inclined to think that such small baud rates are supported by all serial ports (i.e. there is a maximum limit, but smaller values are always available). The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.baudrate(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `BaudRate` property also implies that an exception is thrown only if the value is too large. Why don't you just connect it and try it? Or did you try already?

Comment: It's not selectable because it's not in the drop down list (closest is 2400). I mentioned that 2048 is set in software. It is part of an API that I have to work with, so I assume the Bluetooth device is set to transmit at that rate. I haven't tested if the Port B transmission works because I can't find a good (free) monitoring software that allows you to spy on port transmission.

Comment: @Groo Apparently the Bluetooth device still behaves correctly after I change the application baud rate to a more standard value. So I guess this was a stupid question. Sorry about that.